# Using Kubernetes as docker containers orchestration in PCF

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, pcf

I have a requirement to use Docker containers in PCF deployed in Azure. 
And now we want to use kubernetes as container orchestration.
Does kubernetes can be used here ? 
Or PCF will take care of the container orchasteration ? 
Which one would be the better approach here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PKS](https://pivotal.io/platform/pivotal-container-service) Is Pivotal's answer to running kubernetes in PCF (regardless of IaaS)

Answer (score 1):

[Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF)](https://pivotal.io/partners/microsoft)  is a sophisticated answer from Microsoft to current cloud expectations. PCF offers the best platform to run Microsoft based technology like [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework), and smoothly supports enterprise Java application. You can run [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io) there with fine results, but to achieve comfortable orchestration and management of containers I suggest reading about [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/) or setting up your own Kubernetes cluster using [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray) utility.